# How to float elements in rows. 

Tags: html, css, html-lists

Here is my last chance for this 'probably' a CSS problem.

This is the problem page. 
http://mentor.com.tr/?page_id=81

The site is built on wordpress. And generated posts are displayed as unordered lists.

```
    <ul class="lcp_catlist">
    <li>
    <li>
    <li>
    ...
    </ul>
```

All the `<li>`'s are floated to the left. But as you will see there's one strange gap on the left row. That is my problem. How can I fix that? I'm going crazy with this.

Gap:

[image]

Comment: You're going to have to specify where the gap is (screenshot with red circle or arrow preferred), and what browser(s) and version(s) you're seeing it in.

Comment: have you tried `margin-left: 0` and `padding-left: 0` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify an explicit height for the li elements

```
ul.lcp_catlist li {
    ...
    height: 240px;
}
```

Comment: +1: I would've suggested a `display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;` solution, but this seems to work too, and it's likely much more cross-browser supported.

Comment: @Nightfirecat you can still post your answer.  Even though this solution helps this particular situation (because the items will generally always be about the same height) it will not help with dynamically sized elements.  Yours would, however.

Comment: True, though, far as I can see, they'll always be similarly-sized, so this really would be the simplest and most straightforward way to go about it.

Answer (score 2):

Try removing float: left and using display: inline-block instead.

Note: Inline-block is not supported in IE6/7, but it will work the same if you apply "display:inline;zoom:1" in an IE6/7 only stylesheet.

Answer (score 1):

Gap occurs because height of image http://mentor.com.tr/wp-content/themes/hybrid/library/images/2011/07/Aycan.jpg is 1 pixel smaller then others. Modify your image style from `extrastyles.css` as following to remove the gap:

```
ul.lcp_catlist img {
    float: left;
    height: 206px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-top: -2px;
    width: auto;
}
```